# C# How to read byte array from PDF, but ignore metadata information from the byte array

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

For example below code will read byte array from file, but it will also read the metadata information

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);
```

The idea here is to compare two pdf file content but ignoring the metadata of the file, so if the bytes doesn't have the metadata information we can compare the byte arrays of the respective files.

Comment: I'm afraid you mis-interpret the meaning PDF metadata here. The metadata which is still present in the `byte[]` returned by `File.ReadAllBytes` is contained inside the PDF, not merely carried along aside it in some extra file system stream or property. Thus, you cannot retrieve the bytes without them. You may try to remove them from those bytes but there may not be a canonical way to do so. Your approach to pdf comparison, therefore, is too simplified.